# Embed a Webpage inside popup without using IFrame/Embed/Object/AJAX

Tags: iframe, sharepoint, popup, embed

I have created a popup component using React, while trying to open the sharepoint link with the same popup page using the following

***-Iframe
-Object
-AJAX
-Emebed***

It is showing an security issue:

Error: `Refused to frame 'https://abcd.sharepoint.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com *.officeapps.live.com *.office.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com *.dynamics.com *.microsoft.com"`.

Is there any way I can open the share point link inside the popup I have created

Thanks

Comment: What kind of component is that? Is it a teams tab?

Comment: It is simple function component, designed like a Popup, I am able to open other links except the sharepoint link https://abcd.sharepoint.com/ @Nikolay

Comment: I think "function component" refers to react. What I meant, is how do you integrate it in SharePoint?

Comment: I AM NOT DOING ANY INTEGRATION IN SHAREPOINT @Nikolay[trying to open the sharepoint link inside my popup page build using react]

Comment: I see. It is not allowed to open sharepoint pages in third-party applications (more precisely, specifically disallowed). There are some workarounds, but they apply more on-premise sharepoint and admin access: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140253/display-sharepoint-online-in-an-iframe-on-different-domain. Meaning, there is nothing you can do in your app to show the SharePoint page.